# I am not able to grab the date from the DateEntry using tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkcalendar import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

def Date_func():
    print(startdateEntry.get())
    print(enddateEntry.get())
    
middle_frame=Frame(root,bg='#80c1ff',bd=10)
middle_frame.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.25,relwidth=0.75,relheight=0.2,anchor='n')

#Date and Time Entry boxes and buttons
StartHR=StringVar()
EndHR=StringVar()
StartMN=StringVar()
EndMN=StringVar()
StartDate=StringVar()
EndDate=StringVar()
StartHR.set('HH')
EndHR.set('HH')
StartMN.set('MM')
EndMN.set('MM')
starthourEntry=Entry(middle_frame,text=StartHR,width=5).grid(row=0,column=0)
endhourEntry=Entry(middle_frame,text=EndHR,width=5).grid(row=1,column=0)
startminuteEntry=Entry(middle_frame,text=StartMN,width=5).grid(row=0,column=1)
endminuteEntry=Entry(middle_frame,text=EndMN,width=5).grid(row=1,column=1)
startdateEntry = DateEntry(middle_frame,width=30,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=2020).grid(row=0,column=2)
enddateEntry = DateEntry(middle_frame,width=30,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=2020).grid(row=1,column=2,padx=30,pady=10)
selectStartDate_button=Button(middle_frame,text='StartDate',command=Date_func).grid(row=0,column=3)
selectEndDate_button=Button(middle_frame,text='EndDate',command=Date_func).grid(row=1,column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to capture the date selected in the DateEntry but failed to do so,I am getting "
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"
I tried DateEntry.get_date as well.

Comment: @Minion Jim , Any idea on this??

Comment: The problem is your saying `DateEntry(...).grid(...)` which returns `None` so instead say `startdateEntry = DateEntry(..)` in one line and then `startdateEntry.grid(...)` in the next line, and also use `startdateEntry.selection_get()` to get the selected value

Comment: @CoolCloud, thanks a lot..such a silly mistake!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are saying `DateEntry(...).grid(...)` in the same line, which returns `None`, it is not recommened to not do so and is a bad practice. So to fix it simply say it in two different lines, like:

```
startdateEntry = DateEntry(middle_frame,width=30,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=2020)
startdateEntry.grid(row=0,column=2)
```

This is recommended to be done for all similar widgets on which you want to use attributes like `get()`, `insert()`, `cget()` and so on..

Then to get selection from this, I think you have to say `startdateEntry.selection_get()` instead of using the `get()` method.

Also as a side tip :-

- `Entry` widget does not have `text` argument, unlike `Button` or `Label`, perhaps you meant `textvariable`?

Hope it cleared your doubts, do let me know if any doubts.

Cheers

Comment: @pbeginner Very early reply :P

Answer (score 0):

I removed the .grid() to next line and get the work done.